# Naudio already allocated calling waveoutopen

Tags: c#, naudio

I have a problem with frequent playback of the same sound. If I often click Button I get an error "Already allocated waveoutOpen calling." How do I clean waveOut? How do it? It's my code:

```
        public WaveFileReader reader1;
```

it's button:

```
        if (radioButton1.Checked == true)
        {
         reader2 = new WaveFileReader(Application.StartupPath + "\\Dzwieki\\Piano\\D piano.wav");

        }
        else if (radioButton2.Checked == true)
        {
            reader2 = new WaveFileReader(Application.StartupPath + "\\Dzwieki\\Organ\\D organ.wav");
        }

        z2 = new NAudio.Wave.WaveOut(); 
        z2.Init(reader2);
        z2.Play();
```

Comment: Did you get to the bottom of this? I've just hit the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

It May Be Because The Audio Driver Is Used By Another Process/Application. That Error Was Occuring With Me While Debugging My App. At The Same Time, I Was Playing A Song From FL Studio With ASIO4ALL v2 Driver. When I Closed FL Studio And Tried To Debug Again. The Exception Disappeared (in Other Words, Stopped Displaying Or Occuring). So, May Be The Audio Driver Is Being Used By Another Process/Application. Try To Close That Process Which Is Using The Audio Driver And Try To Run Your Application Again.

Comment: Please don't capitalise the start of every word - it makes it *much* harder to read, at least for me.

Comment: Ok, as you say.